# How to handle `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged` event in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, event-handling

I've tried to handle the routed event `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged` of `DataGrid` in obvious way:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged">
       <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="ScrollChangedHandler" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

But `ScrollChangedHandler` did not even fired.

Then, I've found [this article about handling events](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.co.il/2009/05/mvvm-invoking-command-on-attached-event.html), but I could not figure out what xml namespace(`xmlns`) is used for `mvvmjaco`:

```
<Image Width="360" Height="177" Source="Resources\PlayerArea.png">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <mvvmjoy:RoutedEventTrigger RoutedEvent="s:Contacts.ContactDown">
          <mvvmjaco:CommandAction Command="{Binding TouchCommand}" />
      </mvvmjoy:RoutedEventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Image>
```

`mvvmjoy` uses this class [from the article](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.co.il/2009/05/mvvm-invoking-command-on-attached-event.html):

```
public class RoutedEventTrigger :EventTriggerBase<DependencyObject>
{
    RoutedEvent _routedEvent;    
    //The code omitted for the brevity
}
```

Basically, I have two questions:

1. What class or library should I use for `mvvmjaco` xml namespace?
2. How I can handle `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged` event in my viewModel with its arguments?

Comment: You can write an attached-property with an ICommand where the `ScrollChanged`-Event is subscribed and if it changes your command will be called

Comment: @Tomtom could you show some example. link is better:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would solve it with the following Attached-Property:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class DataGridExtensions
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollChangedCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ScrollChangedCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(DataGridExtensions),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand), OnScrollChangedCommandChanged));

        private static void OnScrollChangedCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = d as DataGrid;
            if (dataGrid == null)
                return;
            if (e.NewValue != null)
            {
                dataGrid.Loaded += DataGridOnLoaded;
            }
            else if (e.OldValue != null)
            {
                dataGrid.Loaded -= DataGridOnLoaded;
            }
        }

        private static void DataGridOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
            if (dataGrid == null)
                return;

            ScrollViewer scrollViewer = UIHelper.FindChildren<ScrollViewer>(dataGrid).FirstOrDefault();
            if (scrollViewer != null)
            {
                scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += ScrollViewerOnScrollChanged;
            }
        }

        private static void ScrollViewerOnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = UIHelper.FindParent<DataGrid>(sender as ScrollViewer);
            if (dataGrid != null)
            {
                ICommand command = GetScrollChangedCommand(dataGrid);
                command.Execute(e);
            }
        }

        public static void SetScrollChangedCommand(DependencyObject element, ICommand value)
        {
            element.SetValue(ScrollChangedCommandProperty, value);
        }

        public static ICommand GetScrollChangedCommand(DependencyObject element)
        {
            return (ICommand)element.GetValue(ScrollChangedCommandProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

The class `UIHelper` looks like:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    internal static class UIHelper
    {
        internal static IList<T> FindChildren<T>(DependencyObject element) where T : FrameworkElement
        {
            List<T> retval = new List<T>();
            for (int counter = 0; counter < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); counter++)
            {
                FrameworkElement toadd = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, counter) as FrameworkElement;
                if (toadd != null)
                {
                    T correctlyTyped = toadd as T;
                    if (correctlyTyped != null)
                    {
                        retval.Add(correctlyTyped);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        retval.AddRange(FindChildren<T>(toadd));
                    }
                }
            }
            return retval;
        }

        internal static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject element) where T : FrameworkElement
        {
            FrameworkElement parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as FrameworkElement;
            while (parent != null)
            {
                T correctlyTyped = parent as T;
                if (correctlyTyped != null)
                {
                    return correctlyTyped;
                }
                return FindParent<T>(parent);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can write in the definition of your `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}" extensionsNamespace:DataGridExtensions.ScrollChangedCommand="{Binding ScrollCommand}"/>
```

And in your ViewModel you have an `ICommand` which looks like:

```
private ICommand scrollCommand;
public ICommand ScrollCommand
{
    get { return scrollCommand ?? (scrollCommand = new RelayCommand(Scroll)); }
}

private void Scroll(object parameter)
{
    ScrollChangedEventArgs scrollChangedEventArgs = parameter as ScrollChangedEventArgs;
    if (scrollChangedEventArgs != null)
    {

    }
}
```

**For the first your question(special thanks to [Andy ONeill and Magnus Montin](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c3e9fad4-16ee-4744-8b0e-1ea0abfc5da7/how-to-handle-scrollviewerscrollchanged-event-in-mvvm?forum=wpf) ):**

`MVVMJaco` is xmlns:mvvmjaco="galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
And the libraries needed are:

- GalaSoft.MVVmLight
- GalaSoft.MVVmLight.Extras
- GalaSoft.MVVmLight.Platform

Answer (score 2):

I don't know `mvvmjaco` but I have some hint for 2nd question. You cann't add handler to `ScrollChanged` directly from `DataGrid`. You can extend `DataGrid` and add custom event there. For example:

```
public class ExtendedDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public event ScrollChangedEventHandler ScrollChanged;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)GetTemplateChild("DG_ScrollViewer");

        scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += OnScrollChanged;
    }

    protected virtual void OnScrollChanged(ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollChangedEventHandler handler = ScrollChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    private void OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnScrollChanged(e);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<local:ExtendedDataGrid>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="ScrollChanged">
                <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}"
                                     MethodName="OnScrollChanged" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </local:ExtendedDataGrid>
```

handler:

```
public void OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Seems that mvvmjaco:CommandAction is an action to invoke command from your ViewModel. You can use i:InvokeCommandAction as substitute.
2. You can use RoutedEventTrigger from the article you've linked to handle scroll changed event.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ScrollChangedTest.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScrollChangedTest"
                mc:Ignorable="d"
                xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
                Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <local:RoutedEventTrigger RoutedEvent="ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged">
                <local:CustomCommandAction Command="{Binding ScrollCommand}" />
            </local:RoutedEventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ScrollData}" />
</Grid>

</Window>
```

ViewModel & stuff:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    ObservableCollection<DataItem> _dataItems = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<DataItem> DataItems { get { return _dataItems; } }

    private TestCommand _scrollCommand;
    public ICommand ScrollCommand { get { return _scrollCommand; } }

    public string ScrollData { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            _dataItems.Add(new DataItem() { Field1 = i.ToString(), Field2 = (i * 2).ToString(), Field3 = (i * 3).ToString() });
        }

        _scrollCommand = new TestCommand(OnScroll);
    }

    private void OnScroll(object param)
    {
        ScrollChangedEventArgs args = param as ScrollChangedEventArgs;

        if (args != null)
        {
            ScrollData = $"VerticalChange = {args.VerticalChange}; VerticalOffset = {args.VerticalOffset}";
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ScrollData)));
        }
    }
}

public class DataItem
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }

}

public class TestCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public TestCommand(Action<object> execute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

RoutedEventTrigger from the article:

```
public class RoutedEventTrigger : EventTriggerBase<DependencyObject>
{
    RoutedEvent _routedEvent;

    public RoutedEvent RoutedEvent
    {
        get { return _routedEvent; }
        set { _routedEvent = value; }
    }

    public RoutedEventTrigger()
    {
    }
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        Behavior behavior = base.AssociatedObject as Behavior;
        FrameworkElement associatedElement = base.AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement;

        if (behavior != null)
        {
            associatedElement = ((IAttachedObject)behavior).AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement;
        }
        if (associatedElement == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Routed Event trigger can only be associated to framework elements");
        }
        if (RoutedEvent != null)
        {
            associatedElement.AddHandler(RoutedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(this.OnRoutedEvent));
        }
    }
    void OnRoutedEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnEvent(args);
    }
    protected override string GetEventName()
    {
        return RoutedEvent.Name;
    }
}
```

CustomCommandAction class for passing args to the command

```
public sealed class CustomCommandAction : TriggerAction<DependencyObject>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(CustomCommandAction), null);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomCommandAction), null);

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)this.GetValue(CommandProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
        }
    }

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            ICommand command = this.Command;
            if (command != null)
            {
                if (this.CommandParameter != null)
                {
                    if (command.CanExecute(this.CommandParameter))
                    {
                        command.Execute(this.CommandParameter);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (command.CanExecute(parameter))
                    {
                        command.Execute(parameter);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If ScrollChangedEventArgs are required as a parameter to command, then custom TriggerAction can be implemented, like in code here http://wpfplayground.com/2014/01/18/invokecommandaction-with-eventargs-as-command-parameter/,

Comment: Edited post to introduce complete solution for DataGrid. TextBlock at the bottom is binded to ScrollData property and is updated by ScrollCommand, that in turn is triggered by scroll changed event