# How bind command to nested event?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have richTextBox and wanna bind command to event of ScrollBar.Scroll with help xmlns:i=http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity.
I tried, but it donst work:

```
<RichTextBox >
    <RichTextBox.Document>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <ScrollBar>
                    <behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <behaviors:EventTrigger EventName="Scroll">
                            <behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=views:MainWindow}}"/>
                        </behaviors:EventTrigger>
                    </behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
                </ScrollBar>
                <Run Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
                </Run>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox.Document>
</RichTextBox>
```

so, above code is my situation because i have richtextbox and run with binding to text. I try bind exactly event of ScrollBar.Scroll to Command. I can bind any event of TextBox, but idn how bind events of ScrollBar inside TextBox. I mean textBox has ScrollBar which has events.  Maybe Sombody know: is it possible at all?

if you know answer for usual textbox it will also help me. I just wanna know possible it or not. Thank you.

Comment: It's still not totally clear what you're actually trying to do, but check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34272606/967885 which could be a useful pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this implementation and fit it to your needs.

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"

<ScrollBar>
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behavior:ScrollBehavior ScrollCommand="{Binding MyScrollCommand}" />
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ScrollBar>
```

```
public class ScrollBehavior : Behavior<ScrollBar>
    {
        public ICommand ScrollCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ScrollCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ScrollCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ScrollCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ScrollBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null,
                OnScrollCommandChanged));

        private static void OnScrollCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var behavior = d as ScrollBehavior;

            if(behavior != null)
            {
                behavior.CommandChanged();
            }
        }

        private void CommandChanged()
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.Scroll += AssociatedObject_Scroll;
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            ScrollCommand.Execute(null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: wtf. i didnt know it and idn it will help to me or not. but it looks interesting and amazing. so I accept it

Comment: The whole point is to access the AssociatedObject, and you can directly access any event from it. Keep in mind that with TextBoxes you'll need to find the ScrollViewer from the VisualTree.

Comment: You don't need to access the scrollbar directly - you can bind to the ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged event within the RichTextBox. Just set VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible". No need to create a scrollbar within the rich text document. See my comment on the original question for a useful link.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `UpdateText` is the command and it's a property of  `MainWindowViewModel` [the `DataContext` of `MainWindow`], the binding should be

```
<behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.UpdateText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

I'd also suggest that `UpdateText` be renamed to `UpdateTextCommand` just to make it clear what it is.

Comment: No, I want bind exactly event of ScrollBar.Scroll to Command. I can bind any event of TextBox, but idn how bind events of ScrollBar inside TextBox. I mean textBox has ScrollBar which has events. Unfortunately I can't take that as an answer. Maybe do you know: is it possible at all?